# How to set WPF ListView row height?

Tags: wpf, listview, layout, row-height

I've got a listView displaying a few text records. I need to increase the height of rows (working on a touch screen so I need thicker rows) without increasing the font size.

This is probably pretty trivial but I have no clue and can't find much on google.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can set the height of all `ListViewItems` in a `ListView` by using `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 10):

Or you could use styles to set it for all listviews. Here scoped to within a window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="100"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```

Comment: This is actually quite neat.

Answer (score 3):

In **XAML**

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel>
                <ListView x:Name="myListView">
                    <ListViewItem Height="50">Test</ListViewItem>
                    <ListViewItem Height="30">Test</ListViewItem>
                </ListView> 
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

In C# Codebehind

```
    foreach (ListViewItem lv in myListView.Items)
    {
        lv.Height = 30;
    }
```

Hope you getting the Idea.

Comment: ListViewItem does not have a Height property.