# Is there anyway to wrap the text in the ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have message is too long to fit in the column. I have table with four columns my fourth column is "Message" which has string long string and it doesnot fit in columnwidth. I want to Make the text in column as Warp so that all the text is visible to the user.

```
  ListViewItem lv = new ListViewItem();
                    lv.Text = det_view.filename;
                    lv.SubItems.Add(det_view.number.ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(det_view.Date_Time.ToString());
                    lv.SubItems.Add(det_view.Message); // here the string too long and need wrap the message
                    listView1.Items.Add(lv);
```

Regards

Comment: Why haven't you accepted answers on 70% of your questions?

Answer (score 2):

Short of having your listviewitems ownerdrawn, you might have a look at [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html).  It will wordwrap just fine and may suite your needs.

Answer (score 2):

If You feel some license problems with `ObjectListView`, you can use native .Net `ListView`.

It can also wordwrap in `view=Details` **and** setting `smallImageList`

(with picture height = 32 or more).

[image: Example of native ListView]

Comment: But How ? I am using VS 2008 and Windows CE application. Is it possible to achieve this ?

Comment: This does seem to work, thought every row is the same height. Also some cells don't seem to wrap but get one line cut off with an ellipsis.

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Better ListView](http://www.componentowl.com/better-listview) component, which supports multi-line items with varous text wrapping and trimming methods:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a class inheriting from ListView that will grow your row height to fit the text in a column. I believe the default will not word break. So you would need to implement wordbreak if that's something you want.

```
class WordWrapListView : ListView
{
    private const int LVM_FIRST = 0x1000;
    private const int LVM_INSERTITEMA = (WordWrapListView.LVM_FIRST + 7);
    private const int LVM_INSERTITEMW = (WordWrapListView.LVM_FIRST + 77);

    private Graphics graphics;

    public WordWrapListView()
    {
        this.graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
        base.View = View.Details;

        this.AutoSizeRowHeight = true;

    }

    //overriding WndProc because there are no item added events
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            // Detect item insert and adjust the row size if necessary based on the text
            // add in LVM_DELETEITEM and LVM_DELETEALLITEMS and reset this.rowHeight if you want to reduce the row height on remove
            case WordWrapListView.LVM_INSERTITEMA:
            case WordWrapListView.LVM_INSERTITEMW:
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = this.Items[this.Items.Count - 1];

                    for (int i = 0; i< lvi.SubItems.Count; ++i)
                    {
                        ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvsi = lvi.SubItems[i];

                        string text = lvsi.Text;

                        int tmpHeight = 0;
                        int maxWidth = this.Columns[i].Width;

                        SizeF stringSize = this.graphics.MeasureString(text, this.Font);

                        if (stringSize.Width > 0)
                        {
                            tmpHeight = (int)Math.Ceiling((stringSize.Width / maxWidth) * stringSize.Height);

                            if (tmpHeight > this.rowHeight)
                            {
                                this.RowHeight = tmpHeight;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

    private void updateRowHeight()
    {
        //small image list hack
        ImageList imgList = new ImageList();
        imgList.ImageSize = new Size(this.rowHeight, this.rowHeight);
        this.SmallImageList = imgList;
    }

    [System.ComponentModel.DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool AutoSizeRowHeight { get; set; }

    private int rowHeight;
    public int RowHeight 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.rowHeight;
        }
        private set
        {
            //Remove value > this.rowHeight if you ever want to scale down the height on remove item
            if (value > this.rowHeight && this.AutoSizeRowHeight)
            {
                this.rowHeight = value;
                this.updateRowHeight();
            }
        }
    }

    // only allow details view
    [Browsable(false), Bindable(false), DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new View View
    {
        get
        {
            return base.View;
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code is helpful, just i d like to have a precision about LVM_FIRST, why 0x1000 value ? and also in updateRowHeight, i don't really understand the hack, can you explain me please ?

Comment: By overriding WndProc we are basically intercepting the Windows message loop so that we can respond to events not explicitly defined by the listview. The definitions for LVM_* come  from Commctrl.h; they are Windows constants.
The actual ability to update the row height came from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563863/c-sharp-change-listview-items-rows-height

that is unfortunately all I know about the "hack".

Answer (score 1):

May not be what you need but my solution was to switch to the build-in DataGridView control.