# c# How can I get max row counts on ListView on screen

Tags: c#, listview

I want to make a bulletin board using listview because I have too many row to show.

When I use the Listbox in C#
I can get single Item height and Listbox height , so I can calculate max row count using these. total row counts.(Listbox height / single item height = max row counts)

But in listview there's no item height, so I can't get the max row counts of it. Is there any way to get total row counts?

(Not the total registered listview item counts, but the max displayable item counts. Sorry for my bad expression.)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe [C# Change ListView Item's/Row's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563863/c-sharp-change-listview-items-rows-height) can be help you.
ImageList's height can be applied for each row's height.