# Create OwnerDraw ListView in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, listview, ownerdrawn

I'm pretty new to Visual Basic. I want to display entries a little nicer. I searched a bit and came across the OwnerDraw function. But now I have the following problem: I can't find anything about this function or what functions there are. Could someone post me a small snippet of code or a few good starting points for learning these functions? I would be happy if someone could give some good tips.

I want something that looks like this picture.

[image: What the end result should look like]

Of course, not that complex; it should simply be an image on the far left, and to the right of the image, there should be three labels.

Comment: Take a read of this page as a starter: [ListView.DrawItem Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

Comment: You need a hack to get the listview item large enough.  Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6563863/c-sharp-change-listview-items-rows-height).  Or consider a FlowLayoutPanel, filled with UserControls, if the number of items is limited.

Comment: Are you committed to a particular UI technology?  Your goal looks like it would be straightforward to do in WPF with an items control and a data template.