# wpf listbox row height

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've created a listbox in wpf and I'm adding items to the listbox dynamically upon a button be clicked. I was wondering how I can set the overall height for each row in the listbox to a specific value?

I've search around online and found this similar example but I'm not entirely sure how to integrate this solution into mine. Hopefully someone can help. Thank you guys.

[How to set WPF ListView row height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1244090/how-to-set-wpf-listview-row-height)

```
<Window x:Class="stadio.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Stadio" Height="350" Width="525" Background="#FF212121">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="uiFileList" BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Gainsboro" Margin="6"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Should be very identical to the example you found which demonstrate the same but using listview. You only need to change `ListView...` to `ListBox...` :

```
<ListBox x:Name="uiFileList" BorderThickness="0" 
         Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="Gainsboro" 
         Margin="6">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```